# pairwise variance ratio in Stata

Tags: variance, stata

Suppose, I want to compute the pairwise correlation in Stata, then I do the following:

```
sysuse auto
pwcorr
```

Now, I want to compute the variance for each variables (numeric) and then obtain variance ratios of all possible combinations. For example, I have :

```
   sum 
     Variable |       Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+--------------------------------------------------------
        make |         0
       price |        74    6165.257    2949.496       3291      15906
         mpg |        74     21.2973    5.785503         12         41
       rep78 |        69    3.405797    .9899323          1          5
    headroom |        74    2.993243    .8459948        1.5          5
-------------+--------------------------------------------------------
       trunk |        74    13.75676    4.277404          5         23
      weight |        74    3019.459    777.1936       1760       4840
      length |        74    187.9324    22.26634        142        233
        turn |        74    39.64865    4.399354         31         51
displacement |        74    197.2973    91.83722         79        425
-------------+--------------------------------------------------------
  gear_ratio |        74    3.014865    .4562871       2.19       3.89
     foreign |        74    .2972973    .4601885          0          1

.
```

This gives the standard deviation for all variables. Now if I want to compute the variance ratio of price and mpg, then this will be given by: var_ratio_pm=variance of price/variance of mpg and var_ratio_mp=variance of mpg/variance of price. In sum, I want a matrix of variance ratios.

I wonder whether there is a command in Stata like `pwcorr` for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do something like that (though in a tabular form, rather than a matrix). You can just include the code in a your do-file.

Alternatively, if you want to keep reusing it, put it into a file called varrat.ado, and put it directory where Stata can see it (like ~/ado/personal). You can find such directories with the `adopath` command.

Here's the code:

```
capture program drop varrat
program define varrat
syntax varlist(min=2 numeric) [if] [in] [aw fw iw] [, cw]

tempfile variances
tempvar var1 var2 variance1 variance2 ratio bucket
tempname wgt

if "`weight' `exp'" != "" {
    local `wgt' "[`weight'`exp']"
}

preserve
    collapse (sd) `varlist' `if' `in' ``wgt'', `cw'

    xpose, clear varname
    rename _varname `var2'
    gen double `variance2' = v1^2
    drop v1
    qui save `variances'
    rename `var2' `var1'
    rename `variance2' `variance1'
    cross using `variances'
    qui drop if `var1' == `var2'
    gen double `ratio' = `variance1'/`variance2'

    sort `var1' `var2'
    list `var1' `var2' `ratio', noob table noheader sepby(`var1')
restore
end
```

You can use it like this:

```
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 Automobile Data)

. varrat price mpg weight length in 1/70 if foreign == 1 [iw=rep78], cw
  +---------------------------------+
  |   length        mpg    3.838666 |
  |   length      price   .00003432 |
  |   length     weight   .00129794 |
  |---------------------------------|
  |      mpg     length   .26050717 |
  |      mpg      price   8.942e-06 |
  |      mpg     weight   .00033812 |
  |---------------------------------|
  |    price     length   29133.707 |
  |    price        mpg   111834.57 |
  |    price     weight   37.813758 |
  |---------------------------------|
  |   weight     length   770.45257 |
  |   weight        mpg   2957.5101 |
  |   weight      price    .0264454 |
  +---------------------------------+
```

Should be pretty easy to modify and improve. One bug is that if you have variables named v1 or _varname in your original data, stuff will break (because `xpose` uses those names). Probability weights are precluded since `collapse (sd)` does not allow them. The case-wise option `cw` will restrict the calculations to data where there is no missing data in the varlist.